# Extending base class and using the feature without altering the derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a C++ Base class with some derived classes. If I later extend the base class by inheritance, it there way to reflect the changes in the already derived classes. To make my question more clear, consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

class FourWheelVehicle
{
    public:
        FourWheelVehicle()
        {std::cout<<"FourWheelVehicle created\n";}
};
class Car: public FourWheelVehicle
{
    public:
        Car()
        {std::cout<<"Car created\n";}
};
class Toyota: public Car
{
    public:
        Toyota()
        {std::cout<<"Toyota Car created\n";}
};
class Audi: public Car
{
    public:
        Audi()
        {std::cout<<"Audi Car created\n";}
};
int main()
{
    Toyota t;
    std::cout<<"..............................\n";
    Audi a;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I extend FourWheelVehicle to FourWheelVehicleWithSeatBelt so that all the cars I derived earlier will get the seat belt without altering their code?
I have tried the following:

```
           FourWheelVehicle
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \
            Car          \
            /\            \
           /  \            \
      Toyota Audi    FourWheelVehicleWithSeatBelt

class FourWheelVehicleWithSeatBelt: public FourWheelVehicle
{
    public:
        FourWheelVehicleWithSeatBelt()
        {std::cout<<"FourWheelVehicleWithSeatBelt created\n";}
};
```

The above scheme does not seem to work!

Comment: You said that "all" of the derived classes should get the change, so why create a new class? Just add the seat belts to `FourWheelVehicle`.

Comment: @JaMiT: Sorry for the confusion. I would like to retain the FourWheelClass intact so that somebody can choose from Car with or Without Seat Belt! At the same time, I don't want to e-write all the child classes as the code remains same in all classes!

Comment: Why don't you create a base class seatBelt and derive new classes from FourWheelVehicle AND SeatBelt? : Benz: public FourWheelVehicle, SeatBelt { ... as @Frontoge suggested

Answer (score 1):

A class does not inherit from sibling classes. In your diagram, expecting `Car` to pick up the features of `FourWheelVehicleWithSeatBelt` is like expecting `Toyota` to pick up the features of `Audi`. It does not happen.

To get another class in your inheritance chain, the new class needs to go in the chain, not in a new branch. Since you (for some reason) cannot change the derived classes, they must still inherit from `FourWheelVehicle`. This leaves you looking at something like the following:

```
                  ????
                   /
                  /
                 /
           FourWheelVehicle
               /
              /
             /
            Car
            /\
           /  \
      Toyota Audi
```

There is a straight-forward approach to this. Rename your current `FourWheelVehicle` class to something else (`FourWheelVehicleWithoutSeatBelts`?), then create a new `FourWheelVehicle` class that inherits from `FourWheelVehicleWithoutSeatBelts` and adds seat belts. Or maybe the new `FourWheelVehicle` should inherit from both `FourWheelVehicleWithoutSeatBelts` and a `VehicleWithSeatBelts` class. Perhaps `Vehicle` would be a virtual base class in this scheme.

The naming scheme is odd, but since you cannot change the code of derived classes, you might be stuck with it. This is one of the hazards of starting with an inadequate design. (Note that "inadequate" is not always the fault of the designer. Sometimes it is, but other times the project requirements change unpredictably.)

*(Personally, I would try to get permission to change the `Car` definition so that a saner naming scheme could be used. The children of `Car` would not need to be changed. Sometimes good program design means talking to other people.)*

Answer (score 0):

Well in this instance I'm not sure why you would need to keep from modifying the base class if all derived classes needed this. However if you would still like to do it this way you could do so with multiple inheritance for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class FourWheelVehicle
{
    public:
        FourWheelVehicle()
        {std::cout<<"FourWheelVehicle created\n";}
};
class SeatBelt
{
    public:
        SeatBelt()
        {std::cout<<"Seatbelt created\n";}
};

class Car: public FourWheelVehicle, SeatBelt
{
    public:
        Car()
        {std::cout<<"Car created\n";}
};
```

This will give seatbelt and FourWheelVehicle to Car through public inheritance

Comment: I don't think this is what Soo wanted, because this way derived classes are changed